# Cancelling CSS styles if viewer is using an unsupported browser

Tags: html, css

I'm using CSS animations to make panels of text fade in when a page is loaded.

The problem is that in order for the animations to work properly, I have to set the `opacity:0;` style on the panels (since they animate in one by one. If I didn't do this the 2nd and 3rd panels would be visible, and then would disappear and fade in after a delay - you'll see what I mean in a minute).

However, if the viewers is using a browser that doesn't support CSS3 animations, then `opacity`'s value is never set to `1`, meaning the text will stay invisible.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could fix this, preferably avoiding the use of JS? Ideally I want to make a change to the CSS to eliminate the `opacity:0;` style (if possible).

**Current code**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

  <title>3tianne | Homepage</title>

  <link href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="resources/bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <style type="text/css">
   @keyframes fade {
    from {
     opacity:0;
    }
    to {
     opacity:1;
    }
   }

   #main {
    opacity:0;
    padding:100px 0 50px 0;
    text-align:center;

    animation:fade 1s forwards;
    animation-delay:3s;
   }
   #main > h1 {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:60px;
   }
   #main > p {
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:italic;
   }

   #content #left {
    opacity:0;

    animation:fade 1s forwards;
    animation-delay:1s;
   }
   #content #right {
    opacity:0;
    
    animation:fade 1s forwards;
    animation-delay:2s;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Hi there.</h1>
   <p>I'm 3tianne, and I make things.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
     <h3>Give your group a web presence.</h3>
     <p>Giving your group a great website improves your capabilities in game. Whether it's a web portal controlling certain systems in your places or a social forum for your citizens, a website offers room for your group to expand even more.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
     <h3>Explore all of my services.</h3>
     <p>I offer a wide variety of services such as place/website integration, place design, Lua scripting, backend and frontend web development, graphic design, and can act as a consultant for a wide range of fields.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

**If I don't set** `opacity:o;`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

  <title>3tianne | Homepage</title>

  <link href="resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="resources/bootstrap/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />

  <style type="text/css">
   @keyframes fade {
    from {
     opacity:0;
    }
    to {
     opacity:1;
    }
   }

   #main {
    padding:100px 0 50px 0;
    text-align:center;

    animation:fade 1s forwards;
    animation-delay:3s;
   }
   #main > h1 {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    font-size:60px;
   }
   #main > p {
    margin:0;
    font-size:20px;
    font-style:italic;
   }

   #content #left {
    animation:fade 1s forwards;
    animation-delay:1s;
   }
   #content #right {
    animation:fade 1s forwards;
    animation-delay:2s;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="main" class="container-fluid">
   <h1>Hi there.</h1>
   <p>I'm 3tianne, and I make things.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
     <h3>Give your group a web presence.</h3>
     <p>Giving your group a great website improves your capabilities in game. Whether it's a web portal controlling certain systems in your places or a social forum for your citizens, a website offers room for your group to expand even more.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
     <h3>Explore all of my services.</h3>
     <p>I offer a wide variety of services such as place/website integration, place design, Lua scripting, backend and frontend web development, graphic design, and can act as a consultant for a wide range of fields.</p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you include Modernizr on your site, you can target elements with CSS based on what the browser supports: https://modernizr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that you knew enough to use `forwards` to keep things at full opacity when the animation is done, yet didn't consider using `both` to ensure that they have zero opacity until their animation starts. Using `both` means you don't need the `opacity:0` on the element itself.

```css
@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
#main {
  padding: 100px 0 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
  animation: fade 1s both;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}
#main > h1 {
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  font-size: 60px;
}
#main > p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-style: italic;
}
#content #left {
  animation: fade 1s both;
  animation-delay: 1s;
}
#content #right {
  animation: fade 1s both;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}
```

```html
<div id="main" class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Hi there.</h1>
  <p>I'm 3tianne, and I make things.</p>
</div>
<div id="content" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="left" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <h3>Give your group a web presence.</h3>
      <p>Giving your group a great website improves your capabilities in game. Whether it's a web portal controlling certain systems in your places or a social forum for your citizens, a website offers room for your group to expand even more.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
      <h3>Explore all of my services.</h3>
      <p>I offer a wide variety of services such as place/website integration, place design, Lua scripting, backend and frontend web development, graphic design, and can act as a consultant for a wide range of fields.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm relatively new to CSS3 animations/transitions and I found out about `forwards` from a bit of previous Googling - as you said, the opacity was resetting to 0 after the animation had completed. Didn't know about `both`, though.